# why is AbstractStringBuilder class undocumented by Java API

Tags: java

In Java API, it declares that the public StringBuilder class extends Object, but in actual fact, OpenJDK declares that it extends a package private AbstractStringBuilder class. Question: why cant Java API just declare that it extends AbstractStringBuilder?

OpenJDK - 
public final class StringBuffer
    extends AbstractStringBuilder
    implements java.io.Serializable, CharSequence

Comment: AbstractStringBuilder is not a _public_ class, so it's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a configuration setting used in the `javadoc` command. You can specify which classes you want to include in the generated javadoc. The default setting is `-protected`, which will include `public` and `protected` classes, but not classes from the package or `private` ones. Assuming you have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class TopParentName {}
(package) class MiddleName extends TopParentName {}
public class LeafName extends MiddleName {}
```

When you run the `javadoc` command without the `-package` flag you will see only the classes `TopParentName` and `LeafName` and you will see that `LeafName` will extends from `TopParentName`, even though in the source code it doesn't. But when you use the `-package` flag, you will see all three classes with the correct inheritance chain.

That being said, the official javadocs are most likely not generated with the `-package` or `-private` flag used, therefore the class `AbstractStringBuilder` class is not visible in the generated javadocs.

Comment: @VirtualInquirer: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.